# Pi Nginx php 7 - where are syntax errors shown?

Tags: logs, php

I have loaded phpinfo, seen the location of the ini file ( `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` ), then went `sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` , and changed `error_log` to read `/var/log/php_errors.log`.

Next opened `/var/log/php_errors.log` and added some text to it, saved, and then `sudo chmod +x /var/log/php_errors.log`

When I try and run some php script that I know contains a syntax error, I am not seeing any errors in the browser, and nothing is added to the log file.

Update :
Using OpenMediaVault on the Pi.
Went to OMV > Services > Nginx > Pools > Edit, and turned On 'Display errors'

Now I am getting errors in the browser when I have broken code.

Still not seeing anything in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

as I am using OpenMediaVault and Nginx was installed as a Service on OMV, it captures all the error logs in this file :

`/var/log/nginx/f7a95d11-5bd3-4e69-9744-0f8859ac497d-error.log`